# Does Overriding C# equals operator work for testing list equality as well?

Tags: c#, equality

I have a class which overrides C#'s == operator like this

```
public class Foo
{
    /*Variables and Constructors*/

    public static bool operator ==(Foo a, Foo b) 
    {
         /*Check values for equality*/
    }
}
```

Does that mean that if I run this expression

```
List<Foo> listA == List<Foo> listB
```

It will return true? If not how should I test these lists for equality?

Comment: Have you considered trying it?

Comment: @JoshLeBlanc why try what you can google? Googled this and couldn't find a good, succinct answer so now there will be one

Comment: Note that you can't *override* operators - you can only *overload* them. As for "if I run this expression" - that's an invalid expression to start with, so you'll just get a compile-time error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - `List<T>` does not override `Equals` so it uses reference equality by default.

One possible reason is that there are different definitions of "equality" for collections.  Does order matter?  What about duplicates?

Linq provides a [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567(v=vs.90).aspx) method that you can easily use, and the documentation provides the criteria it uses:

> [Returns] `true` if the two source sequences are of equal length and their corresponding elements are equal according to the default equality comparer for their type; otherwise, `false`.

Comment: Gotcha, so whats the best way to test the lists for equality?

Comment: So SequenceEqual will call my overloaded == operator for each item in the list?

Comment: @NickG It depends on the criteria I mentioned - does order matter?  What about duplicates?  Casing for strings?  There's not one method that works in all cases.

Comment: @NickG No, It will use `IEquatable<T>.Equals` if you implement that interface, otherwise it will use an override of `Object.Equals`. In either case it will use `GetHashCode` first to see if the two objects _could_ be equal.

Comment: @NickG FYI the [Microsoft Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147.aspx) recommend that you _don't_ overload `==` in mutable types.  You should just override `Equals` (and optionally implement `IEquatable<T>` for a type-safe equality check)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
listA.SequenceEqual(listB);
```

it will call the default equality comparer for the type. I'm pretty sure that means you have to provide an equals() methods implementation for your class (rather than and overloading the  == operator).